# How to check if a process is waiting due to call to wait() or waitpid()?

Tags: linux-kernel, wait, waitpid

I see that in `sys_wait4` (that is reached through calls to `wait()` or `waitpid()`) we insert the current process into a special queue that is saved in its struct task:

```
DECLARE_WAITQUEUE(wait, current);    
add_wait_queue(&current->wait_chldexit,&wait);
```

So if I want to check if a certain process is waiting due to call to `wait()` or `waitpid()` I need to check if it's in its own (???) wait_chldexit queue?

So only the process itself could be inserted into its own wait_chldexit queue?

Did I get it right?

This is linux kernel 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, waitqueue `current->wait_chldexit` may contain either single element for current process or non elements at all.

No one wakes up given waitqueue, instead waiting is broken by a signal arised from the child thread.

By checking this waitqueue for some thread, you may detect whether that the thread is blocked in `wait()` or `waitpid()` call.